# Function returning undefined, I know it's to do with the non-return but I am struggling to solve

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I have a function that takes a variable called (compactArray) (there is another function to produce and return a compact array that works fine)

I know it's because my function is not returning any value, but I am struggling to solve the return = undefined.

the code is below

```
let a = null;
let b = null;
let operand = null;
let total = null;



function testGrab (compactArray) {
    if(compactArray == typeof(Number) && a == null) {
     return a = compactArray;
    } else if (compactArray == typeof(Number) && a !== null){
        return b = compactArray;
    } else if (compactArray == typeof(String)){
        return operand = compactArray; 
    }
  return total
};


const compactArray = 467; 

console.log(testGrab(compactArray));
console.log(a)
```

I want this function to take the compactArray returned from a different function and assign it to the correct variable a,b,operand.

is this possible, or would I need to make a function to return the relevant if statement, and then create another function to assign the returned value to the correct variable?

I know it's because my function is not returning anything but I am stumped at the moment.

Comment: That's not how you use `typeof`. Check the examples in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#basic_usage).

Comment: You wanted to check if the type of compactArray is a number so you had to do that :

if(typeof(compactArray) == "number" && a == null) ...

Comment: "compactArray" and is a single number?, would it be an array in the future?

Comment: Hey compact array is a misleading named admitted, it is an array, that gets turnt into a string, then back int oa number so it is the correct value integer, it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether compactArray's type is a number:

change this statement "if(compactArray == typeof(Number) && a == null)"

to this statement "if("number" == typeof(compactArray) && a == null)"